# How to Select only Date Hour and Minutes from 2017-09-27 15:39:36.000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have a column in my table (having value- **2017-09-27 15:39:36.000**).

I want to select only Date, Hour, Minutes (i.e:- **2017-09-27 15:39**) from column.

Can anyone please tell me how to select.?

Comment: What is the data-type of that column? datetime, datetime2 or something else.

Comment: Do you want to _display_ the output you showed us, or do you want to zero out the seconds component?  These are not the same thing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:- I want display as it is i shown i.e :- 2017-09-27 15:39

Comment: `CONVERT(varchar(16), GETDATE(), 120)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:- Is there any other solution for that..?

Comment: What is wrong with that solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to format the date:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('2017-09-27 15:39:36.000' AS DATETIME), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')
-- 2017-09-27 15:39
```

Here is a [list of available format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: Only i need to select 2017-09-27 15:39 and :00.000 not to show

Comment: @Sanjiv see revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use `CONVERT` with a mask matching the format you want:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(16), GETDATE(), 120)

2018-09-28 07:58
```

### Demo

We convert to `varchar(16)` explicitly so that only the hour and minute components are retained.

Answer (score 0):

Use the datepart function which can extract specific parts of the date value.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017